# Servlet - Tomcat Path

Tags: servlets, tomcat6

I have a problem with my servlet engine i.e. Tomcat.  I am using Windows-7 as my OS.    I have installed my Tomcat into this folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0.

I have set my classpath to following:

C:>SET CLASSPATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\lib\servlet-api.jar"

For running the servlet application i compiled my servlet program and generated the class file. I can easily compile my programs and get a class files.

But when i try to run the tomcat http://localhost:8080/ it gives me the status code 404 - File not Found..Why so??

Thanks..

Comment: The problem is that i can't even see the index page of the tomcat. Forget about the syntax i wrote in my servlet program or web.xml..I want to simply see the index page or the homepage of tomcat..thnks..

Comment: There is no Tomcat index page.  The admin console is a separate install.  Have you even bothered to read a shred of the documentation?

Answer (score 2):

Setting the CLASSPATH is unnecessary, even undesirable.  I don't have a CLASSPATH environment variable on any machine that I use.  Tomcat knows where that servlet.jar is.  Your app needs it in order to compile, but the right thing to do is to include that JAR using the -classpath command line option.

Is your servlet in a package?  Tomcat doesn't allow servlets or classes that aren't in packages.

Did you package your servlet into a WAR file?  That would be a good idea.  Use the standard directory structure, put your servlet .class file in the WEB-INF/classes directory, create a web.xml file that describes your servlet, and package all of it into a WAR.

You should go through [this](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/appdev/index.html) carefully.

If you create a foo.war file, and put that in the Tomcat /webapps directory, you'll access it using this URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/foo/<servlet-name-here>
```

The HTTP 404 means that you didn't register your web app properly.  The web server/Tomcat can't associate a resource with the URL you gave it.

Comment: I would prefer an up vote and acceptance to your thanks.  That's worthless to me.

Comment: Sorry but i think i am not clear what to ask as you are not getting me.The page that you said above to go carefully is not displayed in my web-browser. Apache Tomcat 6.0 index page. There's problem with the installation or in the path for the tomcat.

Comment: That's a web page, a link back to the Apache documentation for Tomcat.  The URL that I recommended is what you should try AFTER you've done all the other stuff that I recommended.  It won't work until you've packaged and deployed your servlet properly.

Answer (score 1):

This post is not cohererent:

> For running the servlet application i compiled my servlet program and
>   generated the class file. I can easily compile my programs and get a
>   class files.

You need to create a `WAR` i.e. a web application with an associated web descriptor in order to deploy your servlets.

> But when i try to run the tomcat http://localhost:8080/ it gives me
>   the status code 404 - File not

Which file are you talking about? This is the url for Tomcat's web management interface