# Tomcat HomePage not displayed and gives 404 error

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat6

I don't get the Tomcat Home/Welcome Page when I enter `http://localhost:8080`.

I get the following status error message in my browser window:

```
    HTTP Status 404 -
    type Status report
    message
    description The requested resource () is not available. Apache Tomcat/6.0.32
```

The pop up window gets displayed coming with few lines when I try to start the tomcat. I have already set the classpath in my environment variables.

```
Classpath: .,C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\lib\servlet-api.jar;
```

Comment: The tomcat startup scripts set classpath. How are you starting it? What's in the logs?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Servlet - Tomcat Path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047544/servlet-tomcat-path)

Comment: This person has already gotten some good advice that they've either ignored or didn't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways of installing Tomcat, 1. By downloading the extracted package and just setting tomcat home in env variables OR 2. By downloading installable Tomcat setup.

I recommend the second approach in case you are facing issues. That setup will do all the config work for you. Download "Deployer:" binary from site instead of "Core".

http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi